# Как добавить элемент в QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть программа, в которой я пытаюсь добавить элемент в QScrollArea

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, 
QLineEdit, QLCDNumber, QScrollArea


class Prog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("text")

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Prog()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Но в результате выполнения получаю пустое окно. Как правильно добавлять элементы в QScrollArea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сноска из документации:

> If the scroll area is visible when the widget is added, you must show() it explicitly.

При добавлении виджета используйте show(), чтобы виджет отобразился. В вашем случае

```py
self.scrollArea.show()
```

Также используйте

```py
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

для изменяемости размера вашего виджета.

Также уберите

```py
win.show()
```

иначе у вас откроется два окна.

Если вашей задачей является только вывод текста, используйте QTextEdit

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import  QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, 
                             QLineEdit, QLCDNumber, QScrollArea,
                             QVBoxLayout)                                # +


class Prog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("""
            Есть программа, в которой я пытаюсь добавить элемент в QScrollArea.
            Но в результате выполнения получаю пустое окно. 
            Как правильно добавлять элементы в QScrollArea?

                        self.label = QLabel(self)
                        self.label.setText("text")

                        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
                        content_widget = QWidget()
                        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
                        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

                        lay = QVBoxLayout(content_widget)
                        lay.addWidget(self.label)

                        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
                        layout.addWidget(scrollArea)

        """)

#        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
#        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.label)

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(content_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(scrollArea)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Prog()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]